# Storing information as serialized data in Mysql or as individual fields

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a question on the data storing on MySql, what would be a better way of storing something like this:

I am trying to create an application where users can store different customizable form fields, e.g. if i need a contact form, i can create a form with From textfield, Subject dropdown field, Message textarea field, and likewise to have a different form with different form elements. And to addon to that, user can set name, and values or other form attributes to the fields.

However, what will be a better way to store this piece of information, such that it will be easy for retrieve to create a dynamic form for user to change the contents easily, as well as using them?

I could only think about 2 ways of storing them:

1. Within a table with schema like such id, form, element, name, value

   > element_id | form_id | element   | name    | value            |
   >   1          | 1       | textfield | to      | null             |
   >   2          | 1       | selectbox | subject | general, support |
2. As a field within a table, with datatype as BLOB, could be stored as serialize data

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I myself prefer not to use serialized data in my designs. But it really depends on the things you will do with it.

I found [this blog article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/01/21/when-should-you-store-serialized-objects-in-the-database/) describing the ups and downs, which may be helpful to your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have a good idea but it involves different tables.
First create a table Form_fields with fields id , field_name
Second table Attributes with id, attribute
Third table Field_attributes with id , form_field_id and attribute_id. This is a relation table. Now do thebackends with php and mysql.